# Cannot connect to raspbery pi in github actions

Tags: raspberry-pi, github-actions

I'm running an action from github, where I have to connect to my raspberry pi, but the action fails in that part of executing. I'm trying to ssh and when I put the raspberry IP I get timeout and when I put raspberrypi.local I get the following error:

```bash
ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi.local: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

From my personal computer, I can access both hosts, both by ip and raspberrypi.local
Does anyone have any idea what it could be?

Action step:

```bash
Run sshpass -p *** ssh pi@raspberrypi.local "cd Desktop; git pull; python3 main.py"
```

Comment: Your Raspberry Pi is certainly on a different network than the GitHub server that is trying to run your action.  You're going to need something like a static IP address or dynamic DNS service in concert with updating some firewall rules on the router your Pi is connected to to get this to work.

Comment: What would this part of static ip look like? It seems simpler to me, but I don't understand networks very well ;(

Comment: when your github actions runs on the github server, the raspberrypi.local will point to the local of the github server, but the pi is running in your network. Hudson is right ! you need a DNS for your pipeline to know where the pi is sitting to communicate with it .

Comment: @DevBr: Are you using a self-hosted GHA runner? And, is your RPi connected to it? If you're using a GHA-hosted runner and your RPi is connected to your local machine, it won't work. To SSH to RPi, it should publicly be available to be reached by a GHA workflow run. Or, you should use a self-hosted runner and connect your RPi on the same network (among other configuration depending on the runner). Apart from that, what is your use case for SSHing to RPi from your workflow?